# Merge two tables with same primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Example i having some values in Employee with following fields.

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
D#      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL, /* Department number      */
DName       VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Department name        */
Manager#    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Department manager number  */
MSDate      DATE,             /* Manager start date         */
    total_staff_number NUMBER(3),
CONSTRAINT Department_PK PRIMARY KEY(D#),
CONSTRAINT Department_CK UNIQUE(DName)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
E#      CHAR(5)     NOT NULL, /* Employee number        */
Name        VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL, /* Employee name      */
    D#      NUMBER(5),        /* Department number      */
CONSTRAINT Employee_PK PRIMARY KEY(E#),
CONSTRAINT Employee_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (D#) REFERENCES Department (D#)
);
```

In my database. DEPARTMENT = 'SPORTS' = D# = 5, DEPARTMENT = 'GAMES' = D# = 3; 
Merging the DEPARTMENT='SPORTS' INTO DEPARTMENT='GAMES' , and manager will still remain the same, the employee.D#=5 will change to employee.D#=3

```
MERGE INTO EMPLOYEE TARGET
USING EMPLOYEE SOURCE WHERE D#=5 ON (
TARGET.D# = SOURCE.D#;
}
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET SOURCE.D#=3;
UPDATE DEPARTMENT.D# SET total_staff_number = total_staff_number - 1 where DEPARTMENT.D# = SOURCE.D#;
UPDATE DEPARTMENT.D# SET total_staff_number = total_staff_number - 1 where DEPARTMENT.D# = TARGET.D#;
```

but my logic seem like wrong.
any solution?

Comment: 1) You don't have total_staff_number column in your department table; 2) why do you decrease both source and target total, you should increase the the source, decrease the target; 3) update your source.d# after you change the total_staff_number columns. If you do it this way, you are losing the value "3". Both columns' values are "5" during your last two update operations.

Comment: @yigitalp
i already edit with total_staff_number. i alter the table in my database .
hmm. not really sure which 1 should decrease/increase. Question is Games employee will increase when Sport employee merge into that department. So how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the employees from Sports to Games would be simply updating the departpent column to point to the new department. The question is what you are going to do with the dangling department sports afterwards?

*For all employees working in Sports, change to Games.*

```
update employee
   set d# = 3
 where d# = 5;
```

*Count the nr of employees in department Games, and update the employee counter.*

```
update department
   set total_staff_number = (
          select count(*)
            from employee
           where d# = 3
       )
 where d# = 3;
```

Comment: from your code i can't see any merge command, which mean this actually no need to use merge command also can merge the data together?

Comment: The merge statement is typically used when you need to either insert or update. From your description, I understood that you where "merging departments", not really merging in the database sense.